Option --echo for gz topic generates no output on MacOS
I start my simulation environment (Gazebo Garden) as follows:
gz sim -s -v 4 /Users/USER/Desktop/building_robot.sdf
gz sim -s -v 4
gz topic -e -t /keyboard/keypress

There is no output in the bash for the last command. On Windows and Linux there is no problem.
